# how to get multiple queries results in the same page in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

Hy, I am working in codeigniter and I need to get multiple results on the same page. How I can do it.

Look at my code of Model, Controller and view.

Model:

```
function asia(){
     $this->db->distinct();
     $this->db->select();
     $this->db->from('travels_detail t');
     $this->db->join('all_destination a','t.destination = a.destination','inner');
     $this->db->where('region', 'asia');
     $this->db->group_by('t.destination');
     $query= $this->db->get();
     return $query->result_array();

     }
```

controller:

```
function asia(){
        $data['asia'] = $this->travel->asia();
         $this->load->view('testing', $data);
        }
```

view:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table border="1">
    <tr> 
    <td> Departure </td> <td> Destination </td>
    <td> Airline </td> <td> Fare </td>
    <td> Type </td> <td> Via </td>
    </tr>
<?php foreach($asia as $row){ ?>
<?php  
    echo '<tr>
    <td> '.$row['departure'].' </td>
    <td> '.$row['destination'].' </td>
    <td> '.$row['airline'].' </td>
    <td> '.$row['fare'].' </td>
    <td> '.$row['type'].' </td>
    <td> '.$row['via'].' </td>
    </tr>';
}
    ?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I get data of a continent "asia" from my database and display in a table. similarly i have to get some other data on the same page. Help me out please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function asia()
{
    $data = [
        'asia'   => $this->travel->asia(),
        // The fact that the controller method is named `asia`,
        // does not restrict you to only call the asia() method 
        // on your model. Do whatever you want!
        'europe' => $this->travel->europe()
    ];

    $this->load->view('testing', $data);
}
```

Add another table to your view and iterate over the europe data.

Comment: and in view i made another foreach loop ??? for instance foreach($europe as $europe_row) {}

Comment: Yeah, sure, why not?

Comment: Clearly, you need to implement another method on your model. I assumed the new method name is `europe` in my example code.

Comment: Gopal Patel has a good point in his answer. If you want the same functionality, you can just accept a parameter in your method implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Model:

```
function region($value){

     $this->db->distinct();
     $this->db->select();
     $this->db->from('travels_detail t');
     $this->db->join('all_destination a','t.destination = a.destination','inner');
     $this->db->where('region', $value);
     $this->db->group_by('t.destination');
     $query= $this->db->get();
     return $query->result_array();
 }
```

controller:

```
function asia(){
        $data['asia'] = $this->travel->region('asia');
        $data['europe'] = $this->travel->region('europe')
        $this->load->view('testing', $data);
}
```

just use `$europe` way you have used `$asia` in view